# I am trying to find a regular expression for {Strings whose number of 0s is not divisible by 4}, with and without the use of complement.

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions, finite-state-machine

With use of a complement I found:

$$\{ \text{Strings whose number of 0s is divisible by 4\}}^{C} = $$
$$\{\{\{1\}^*\cdot \{0\}\cdot\{1\}^*\cdot\{0\}\cdot\{1\}^*\cdot\{0\}\cdot\{1\}^*\cdot\{0\}\cdot\{1\}^*\}^*\}^{C}$$

I haven't been able to find a regular expression that does not use complement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L = (1^*01^*01^*01^*01^*)^* = \{u \in \{0,1\}^* \mid |u|_0 \equiv 0 \bmod 4 \}$. Then the language you are looking for is 
$$
L(01^* + 01^*01^* + 01^*01^*01^*).
$$ 
Can you see why?

Comment: Yes because L is a string that has exactly multiples of 4 zeros, and you concatenate strings of 1, 2, or 3 zeros to it. But the strings that you concatenate can be replicated as substrings of L so there is no loss of generality. This is what I had but i wasn't sure.

Comment: You got it right...